# Not able to fetch data from unicode between two characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

In parsing of html

```
<div>
<h3>
    <small style="text-align:left;color:gray;">05/23 13:58頃</small> 
    <small>苫小牧市</small><br>
    （支援）苫小牧市新富町1丁目
</h3>
```

I have to fetch data from small bracket '( )' as 支援 in python.  When I am trying to fetch data by command

```
text = div.h3.findAll(text=True, recursive=False)[2].strip()
```

I am getting

```
u'\uff08\u652f\u63f4\uff09\u82eb\u5c0f\u7267\u5e02\u65b0\u5bcc\u753a1\u4e01\u76ee'
```

It is the unicode data of `'（支援）苫小牧市新富町1丁目'`, so I am unable to fetch data from small bracket as `'支援'`

Comment: What are you using to parse HTML? BeautifulSoup or something else?

Comment: @Andrew: do look at the tags. Yes, they are using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup won't help you parse out substrings. You can use Python's string methods to handle this, or use a regular expression.

The opening and closing parentheses here are the U+FF08 and U+FF09 fullwidth parentheses, you could partition the string on those:

```
text.partition(u'\uff08')[-1].partition(u'\uff09')[0]
```

or you could use a regular expression that takes all text between two such codepoints:

```
re.search(ur'\uff08([^\uff09]*)\uff09', text).group(1)
```

They both work for your sample string:

```
>>> print text.partition(u'\uff08')[-1].partition(u'\uff09')[0]
支援
>>> import re
>>> print re.search(ur'\uff08([^\uff09]*)\uff09', text).group(1)
支援
```

The difference lies in how they handle strings without one or both of those parentheses; `re.search()` will return `None` in those cases and you then get an `AttributeError` for trying to use `.group` on that object, while `str.partition()` will either produce an empty string or a partial string:

```
>>> text = u'no parentheses'
>>> text.partition(u'\uff08')[-1].partition(u'\uff09')[0]
u''
>>> text = u'\uff08open parentheses'
>>> text.partition(u'\uff08')[-1].partition(u'\uff09')[0]
u'open parentheses'
>>> text = u'close parentheses\uff09'
>>> text.partition(u'\uff08')[-1].partition(u'\uff09')[0]
u''
```

Pick the method that best suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, It helped me.

Comment: Is there any trick to convert   u'\uff08\u652f\u63f4\uff09\u82eb\u5c0f\u7267\u5e02\u65b0\u5bcc\u753a1\u4e01\u76ee'   in it's original data.

Comment: That *is* the original data. Try printing it.

Comment: Python 2 echoes Unicode string values in a way that is ASCII safe, so any non-ASCII codepoint is echoed using escape syntax. That makes it easy to copy the string value to another Python script with errors.